# Is AutoComplete Possible in a Combo Box?

Tags: vba, combobox

I have created a Userform with a ComboBox for purposes of entering client names and information about their children, their names addresses, etc.  The data entered will be used to populate various legal documents, and in many cases the clients will select their children (and the children's information) repeatedly.  Understanding this to be the case, I have each entry .AddItem'd to the ComboBox List as I enter the data. So far so good.

But I am now trying to set the MatchEntry property (or something else in a manner which will allow me to "find" a former entry in the list and then select it or override it).  The MatchEntryFirstLetter property, if active and nothing matches it, won't allow a new entry, it just flashes-back with the letters I type. MatchEntryComplete forces me to use a former entry (for instance if I have earlier entered the client name in Lower Case, MatchEntryComplete finds the Lower Case name but won't let me override it with an UPPER CASE version.  Ho-hum.

So before I struggle further (and abandon this to MatchEntryNone), is there a way to structure the ComboBox (or is there a form of VBA code) such that as I enter text in the ComboBox it will simply "search" for a match, and then release me to either select the match or override it with a new entry?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Mike

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, `ComboBox` already have that feature.
You just need to:

- set `MatchEntry` to `1 - fmMatchEntryComplete`
- set `Style` to `0 - fmStyleDropDownCombo` which are actually the defaults.

Consider below:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.ComboBox1.List = Array("Entry1", "Option1", "Item3")
End Sub
```

Say we have a `UserForm1` with 1 `ComboBox` named `ComboBox1`.
If we run the form, it will look like below after typing `O` and `p`.

[image]

If you type another letter say `y`, it will automatically be overwritten.

[image]

If the searched match already satisfies your search, the just move on to next control either by using mouse or <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. Is this what you're trying to do or did I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Thanks L42:  But herein lies the problem if the code looks like this instead: Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.ComboBox1.List = Array("Mike", "Option1", "Item3")
End Sub    . . .and then I go to enter MIKE, the box will only let me enter the previously entered "Mike".  Is there a way around this? Thanks, again

Comment: I think the ComboBox needs a "MatchEntryCase" property attendant to the MatchEntryComplete property.  Without it, I am thinking I am stuck with either "None" or no CAPS

Comment: @Mike28 Oh I get it. So "Mike" and "MIKE" should be different. Well, even in logins, that is basically same. The workaround is put additional character on "Mike" which will make it unique. Eg. "Mike L.", "MIKE R."

Comment: Thanks, L42;  "additional character". . . Good point!!   I'm thinking I'll lead with a space, then do the CAPS version, and have each entry checked with a "trim" function before its .AddItem'd to the Combo List.  This should work, I'm thinking.  Thanks again.   Mike